# SSI Expression for simple if else

Tags: apache, if-statement, syntax, expression, ssi

I just discovered Apache SSI expressions and it seems similar to CGI-BIN/PERL in concept, if not as elegant, but I'm having trouble getting a simple variable assignment and evaluation to happen.

All the resources I'm finding are using more complex examples or strip out all the code around the concept so I can't find syntax examples out there for my situation.

I just want to be able to set a variable (preferably to an integer) and evaluate it.  The hope is that the scope of a variable set in a higher file will trickle to the lower files and I can pass variables this way, using web files as scripts.

My current test SSI:

```
<!--#set var="page" value="0"-->
<!--#if expr="@page == '0'" -->
    <!--#include file="./layout.ssi"-->
<!--#elif expr="@page == '1'" -->
    Eat Me
<!--#else -->
    NOPE!
<!--#endif -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it was a silly mistake on my part.

The solution was to use $ to designate variables in the expression.  I was even able to confirm that the variables persist when calling another file, allowing the variables to be "passed".

Correct syntax for this example looks like this:

```
<!--#set var="page" value="0"-->
<!--#if expr="$page == 0" -->
<!--#include file="./layout.ssi"-->
<!--#elif expr="$page == 1" -->
    Eat Me
<!--#else -->
    NOPE!
<!--#endif -->
```

Comment: apparently this is required in expressions, but not when using an echo or set var.